# Mongoose findByIdAndRemove() function doesn't seem to work?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, ejs

When checking the checkbox with a `/POST` method to the server, it passes the item's `ID` back to the script.

Then I try to call the `findByIdAndRemove()` function but it doesn't seem to actually delete the document.

I'm checking with Mongosh (MongoDB new Shell).

NODE:

```
app.post('/delete', function(req, res){

  const checkedItem = req.body.checked;

  Item.findByIdAndRemove(checked);
  
});
```

EJS:

```
<% newListItems.forEach(function(item){ %>

      <form action="/delete" method="post">

        <div class="item">
          <input type="checkbox" onChange="this.form.submit()" name='checked' value='<%= item._id %>'>
          <p> <%=item.name%> </p>
        </div>

      </form>


    <% }); %>
```

'Test' should be deleted when checked: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ujL7Z.png

But 'Test' is still intact: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vomkW.png

With the most recent Mongoose upgrade to version 7.0, they removed callbacks and some methods stoped working the way they did.

I've tried reading their docs about async and await, using `.then` and `.catch` and found no help on the open web since the update is recent.

Comment: Please include code in the question as formatted text, not as images.  https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/2282634

Comment: [_You should use findOneAndDelete() unless you have a good reason not to_](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54629175/283366)

Comment: 1) You should wait for the delete operation to complete. 2) Have you debugged the `req.body.checked` value to make sure it's correct?

Comment: Thanks Joe and Phil for the tips. Yes Phil, I have debugged the query, it works fine.
This post:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75586474/mongoose-stopped-accepting-callbacks-for-some-of-its-functions
helped me, using try, catch and await and async the right way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm also facing the same problem so, I put everything under async function inside post request.

app.js

```
app.post("/delete", function(req,res){

async function myDelete(){
  const checkedItemId = req.body.checkbox;

  const del = await Item.findByIdAndRemove(checkedItemId);

};
myDelete();
res.redirect("/");
});
```

Comment: Yep, that's what also worked for me. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 4):

Check your mongoose version:

`npm list mongoose`

As of version 8 there is no more `.findByIdAndRemove()` in its place you will have to use `.findByIdAndDelete()`

https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/model.html

Answer (score 1):

Use the following snippet of code instead

```js
await Prompt.findByIdAndDelete({ _id: params.id });
```